# Error When Starting Standalone Mule Server

Tags: integration, mulesoft

I get the following error when I tried to start the standalone Mulesoft server: "Bad CPU type in executable". I am using Mule Standalone 3.8.4 on macOS Catalina 10.15.5. Have anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: You will likely need to contact the publisher's support. We do not directly support third-party applications. That said, a cursory search found [this question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250777998) suggesting you can [switch to zsh](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050), but I don't know if that will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. zsh is already my default shell.